# Token distribution to unknown party

Tags: oauth, access-token

If I distribute received OAuth access token (in the background) to multiple other clients who are not part of the original OAuth flow then what could be the security problem? I am kind of trying to achieve the delegation to those parties who are not even present in the OAuth flow something like UMA ...correct me ..I could be totally wrong here

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This is highly related to your use case. As a thumb rule you would not distribute the tokens.

However, you might run into a scenario where your code needs to share the tokens with another app that completes your offering to your customer. An OAuth serverless proxy like Pathfix or UMA do not fall under the category of third party, they provide functionality to your app, so they are more like internal use Libraries, or Processing Servers.

If you provide some more information about your use case, it could be a good discussion for others to reference too :)